# Will resetting Windows 7 to factory remove files in my other drives

Tags: windows-7, windows, reset

I have 4 drives in my HP Pavillion dv6 laptop. I want to reset the Windows 7 to factory condition. But I am concerned about data in my other drives. Its too large to copy. If I reset my Windows7, Will it erase my other drives ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.

> **Factory Reset:** Factory Reset removes all partitions, reformats the entire hard drive, reinstalls the original operating system, and
>   reinstalls all the original hardware drivers and software. This option
>   also recreates the required Recovery partition (usually D:) and UEFI
>   partition (usually E:) and reinstalls the required software. The
>   Factory Reset option returns all of the notebook's software to the
>   condition it was in at the time of purchase. All user changes or
>   additions are removed.

source: http://support.hp.com/in-en/document/c01867418

I believe you should perform a **system recovery**. HP

> **System Recovery**: This option reformats the system drive (usually C:),
>   reinstalls the original operating system, and reinstalls all the
>   original hardware drivers and software. System Recovery does not
>   impact user created partitions. If there are two hard drives, System
>   Recovery modifies only the drive with the operating system.

Answer (score 1):

To clarify... you have 4 separate hard drives installed, not partitions, correct?)

So no, restoring your HP to factory defaults will not affect other drives.  I use an external flash drive for storage and running games, it has never been affected by a factory reset of the main OS drive.